# Add colored bar navigation bar css

Tags: html, css, navigation

I need a colored bar beneath my navigation menu but I don't know how to do this in the right way.

What I need:

[image]

EDIT:
I forgot to ask how I can place the navigation menu at 50% of the height of the logo. I've used a 'static' margin-top of 20px, but is this a good way to do it? i.imgur.com/ApihCfJ.png

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">  
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="/home/" title="Home">Home</a></li>  
        <li><a href="/over-ons/" title="Over ons">Over ons</a></li>  
        <li><a href="/producten/" title="Producten">Producten</a></li>  
        <li><a href="/contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>  
    </ul>  
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#menu  {
    margin-top:40px;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have working demo: http://jsbin.com/olAXoSi/2/

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  margin: -5px ;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0 ;
}

.item-1 {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
.item-2 {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}
.item-3 {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
.item-4 {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Hm, jsBin is somewhat slow today, but +1 for the effort and the nice clean code

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sZ3J/1/)

**CSS**

```
 #menu  {
margin-top:40px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li
{
    display: inline;
}
#menu ul li a {

text-decoration:none;    
    color:#666;

}

#first
{
    border-bottom:2px solid blue;

}

#second
{
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}

#third
{
    border-bottom:2px solid green;
}

#fourth
{
    border-bottom:2px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: This will only create a red line under each item.  I would leave his code the same, and add an ID to each menu item so he can customize the bottom bar color individually.

Comment: Is it a good way to use padding-right for each <li> to adjacent the colors to each other, since the colors are 20 px right from the last character of the <li>

Comment: @user3104933 Maybe margin?  It really doesn't matter.

Comment: oh yes you are right! :) Thank you all for your fast/helpful responses!

Comment: @user3104933 no, don't use paddings for `li` elements, while creating a `LI` as a menu holder, assign padding and styling to the `A` elements. You'll get a better written code and both a wider clickable area. Treat `LI` elements as dummy containers.

Comment: I forgot to ask how I can place the navigation menu at 50% of the height of the logo. I've used a 'static' margin-top of 20px, but is this a good way to do it?
http://i.imgur.com/ApihCfJ.png

Comment: @user2509848 margin doesnt work because the border will not stop 20 px right from each li. So I have to use padding..

Comment: @user3104933 Sounds good.  There are no real rules on how to adjust space looks, except those that apply to accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `:nth-child()` selector for this kind of effect.

Here is how the HTML looks: ( `<!-- -->` removes white space from inline)

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/home/" title="Home">Home</a>
        </li><!--
        --><li><a href="/over-ons/" title="Over ons">Over ons</a>
        </li><!--
        --><li><a href="/producten/" title="Producten">Producten</a>
        </li><!--
        --><li><a href="/contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menu ul li:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid teal;
}

#menu ul li:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid brown;
}

#menu ul li:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid lime;
}

#menu ul li:nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Finally, here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/ZBXtP/1/).

I also made these changes to your CSS for appearance changes:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #2b2b2b;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```